# why str split is not working as expected?

Tags: python, pandas, string, strsplit

I have data frame column as -

```
Date
2025-01-21 00:00:00
2021-12-05 00:00:00
12-MAY-2020/18-SEP-2020
15-JUN-2021/20-JUL-2021
2020-12-05 00:00:00
```

I am using following code to extract the first date from the dates separated by "/"-

```
df["Date2"] = df["Date"].str.split('/', expand=True)[0]
```

I am expecting a output of -

```
Date2
2025-01-21 00:00:00
2021-12-05 00:00:00
12-MAY-2020
15-JUN-2021
2020-12-05 00:00:00
```

But, output is as follows-

```
Date2
nan
nan
12-MAY-2020
15-JUN-2021
nan
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was possibly due to the different datatypes present in 'Date' column:

so use `astype()` to ensure the type:

```
df["Date2"] = df["Date"].astype(str).str.split('/', expand=True)[0]
#OR
df["Date2"] = df["Date"].astype(str).str.split('/').str[0]
```

output of `df`:

```
    Date                        Date2
0   2025-01-21 00:00:00         2025-01-21 00:00:00
1   2021-12-05 00:00:00         2021-12-05 00:00:00
2   12-MAY-2020/18-SEP-2020     12-MAY-2020
3   15-JUN-2021/20-JUL-2021     15-JUN-2021
4   2020-12-05 00:00:00         2020-12-05 00:00:00
```

`Note:` you can check the output of `print(df['Date'].map(type).value_counts())` to verify that